# .NET calling stored procedure: Error converting data type int to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Here is my test stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test
    @Param1 int, 
    @Param2 varchar(10), 
    @Param3 bit, 
    @Output int OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @Output = 99

    SELECT 99

    RETURN -99
```

I am calling from .NET with the values:

- Param3: "true" or 1 (non works better)
- Param2: "Hello"
- Param1: "3"
- Output: "0"

The error comes when calling the function:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim intRes As Integer = sqlDbAdapter.Fill(ds)
```

Any idea why and how to call this. I believe the problem is the `InputOutput` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter 1 Should be a int Not string as it is declared in The procedure

Comment: I never set the SQLDbType or convert parameters. It seems to have always converted parameters to their corresponding datatype at runtime. Except for this InputOutput parameter - any ideas why?

Comment: Not for Sure. But i always Set them to have a more expressive Code and to get a more predictable behavior